# Markers -> Go to Line Number

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I've created a plug-in that adds Markers with the corresponding line numbers. Now, this is great because now it shows up in the Markers view. Is there a way when I double click a row on a Marker, it will go to the line that was indicated by the marker?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to also set a character start and end on your markers for better behavior where supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double clicking in the Markers view (or the Problems, Tasks, ... views) will open the editor for the current marker provided the marker is for an `IFile`.

Once the editor is open it is checked to see if it provides an `IGotoMarker` adapter. If it does the

```
public void gotoMarker(IMarker marker)
```

method of `IGotoMarker` is invoked.

Editors based on the standard `TextEditor` should all provide this adapter.

Comment: Hi @greg-449, does this also apply to the default Problem Viewer of Eclipse?